# Write python code that prints only the expressions that evaluate to True in the given list

Tags: python, arrays, list, loops, if-statement

**Q1**Consider the given list. Write python code that prints only the expressions that evaluate to True in th egiven list.
You may use for loop and if statement(s) as needed. A for loop can iterate over all elements of the list as given below:

```
for item in myList:
   if item == True:

myList = [6<5, 1==3, True or False, 1]
for element in myList:
    if (element == True):
        print(element)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This is not a website where people write code for you so that you don't have
to. If you need help debugging code that you have written, you must post a 
[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and explain the specific problem
with your code.

Comment: `print([item for item in myList if item])`

Comment: `if element == True: print(element)` will never print anything if `element` is an integer, because it will never be equal to `True`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like

It's a bit strange, python will evaluate all of your expressions, so they will remain like True/False as soon as you declare the variable.

I think you want your expressions declared as strings inside a list and then using eval to evaluate strings as python:

```
myList = ["6<5", "1==3", "True or False", "1"]
for item in myList:
    if eval(item):
         print(item)
```

prints the following:

```
True or False
1
```

Comment: I am trying to extract those elements of list which give boolean True value. In my list i enter some expression that give true or false.now i am trying to print those expression which only give true value.

Comment: Have you tried my code? The code will print all of the elements in the list that evaluate to True

Comment: @buran eval() is a way for python to run strings as code (very vague), otherwise al expressions would be true because a boolean of a non empty string is true, you can try to run bool("6<5") and then bool(eval("6<5"))

Comment: Why would you need `eval()` here? OP elements in the sample list are not str.  I am aware what `eval()` does and also that it can be dangerous :-)

Comment: @buran you are right, but I didnt think of any other possible way to print the expressions as he requests, because they are automatically evaluated when declaring myList.

Comment: If you find a problem with OP question - ask them about it and the expected output, don't improvise about sample input. It may well be a problem with their sample data. But you don't know for sure.

Answer (score 0):

The following will never print anything:

```
i = 1
if i == True:
    print(i)
```

Because `i` is an integer, it will never be equal to `True`.

But the following will print:

```
i = 1
if i:
    print(i)
```

Why? Because the `i` in `if i:` is in a boolean context.

`if` expects a True/False value. If it doesn't get one, it has rules for converting other types, such as integers, into `True` or `False`.

`if i:` is NOT the same as `if i == True:`...

Instead it checks that `i` is non-zero.

Why?

A non-zero integer is considered `True` in a boolean context like an if statement. A `0` is considered `False`.

There are various other rules, but the most likely one you'll come across is:

- any non-empty string is `True`. Example: `"Fred"`
- an empty string (`""`) is `False`

Example:

```
name = ""
if name:
    print("Hello " + name)
else:
    print("No name given. Welcome!")
```

This will print `"No name given. Welcome!"`. Here's why:

1. name is an empty string
2. `if name:` expects a True/False value but finds a string instead
3. It follows the string rule for boolean context: if the string is empty, it's `False`, otherwise it's `True`
4. So the `else:` is executed

To correct your code, what you should have written is:

```py
myList = [6<5, 1==3, True or False, 1]
for element in myList:
    # NOT if element == True:
    if element:
        print(element)
```

[This article](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/truthy-and-falsy-values-in-python/) introduces boolean context in more detail.